# Bash: assigning output of command substitution to an integer variable

Tags: bash

In Bash, I need an integer variable, like this:

```
declare -i n_jobs
```

to be assigned as a value the number of current background jobs:

```
jobs | wc -l
```

If I assign it as so:

```
n_jobs=$(jobs | wc -l)
```

is seems like a working integer, e.g.:

```
echo $((++n_jobs))
```

but... printing it (without running the increment above) reminds me that it contains blanks:

```
$ echo "$n_jobs"
$ <space><space><space><space><space>4
```

so I resort to this construct:

```
n_jobs=$(( $(jobs | wc -l) ))
```

to force immediate "casting" to *int*.

Is there a better way to take the output of a command substitution list and assign it to a variable as an *integer*?

Comment: The integer flag in bash is almost never used. Why do you actually care that it's set here?

Comment: Try `$ echo $n_jobs` Instead of `$ echo "$n_jobs"`

Comment: If the flag exists, it marks a variable as _int_, I know I want only _int_ there, why would I _not_ use what seems like a very convenient flag, designed exactly to express this condition?

Comment: Without specifying the integer flag, the spaces I mention appear.. it has its uses!

Comment: The only thing the integer attribute does is causes the RHS of an assignment to be evaluated as an arithmetic expression. It's not as useful as it sounds: `x=7+9` works, but `x=3*(7+9)` still produces a syntax error and needs to be written as `x=$(( 3*(7+9) ))`. A simple comment the first time you assign to a variable stating `# n_jobs is an integer` would work just as well. Also, I cannot reproduce the spaces you are observing.

Comment: @chepner: `n=$(jobs|wc -l);echo "$n"` displays the spaces. How interesting that 7+9 works but 3*(7+9) does not. Absurd, really.. it goes "halfway there" in making it like a `(( ))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still `bash`-specific, but a cleaner way of getting a space-free integer might be:

```
job_pids=( $(jobs -p) )
n_jobs=${#job_pids[@]}
```

A POSIX-compliant version:

```
n_jobs=$( jobs -p | awk '{print NR}' )
```

(The `-p` isn't necessary, but you really don't need anything more than a unique line per job to feed to `awk`, so may as well make the lines as brief as possible.)

Comment: Whoa.. I **like** this one!

Answer (score 3):

It's not really necessary, but you could do something like:

```
n_jobs=$(($n_jobs + 0))
```

Or

```
n_jobs=`expr $(jobs | wc -l)`
```

I would suggest that you actually avoid `declare` ... it exists in only one shell and it is not specified by Posix.

The shell is partly a macro processor and in its standardized form all variables are kept as strings. This is not a big handicap for jobs appropriate for the shell, and adding `declare` and integer variables makes bash only microscopically more suitable for complicated things.

Do those more complicated things in something like Ruby, Python, Perl, Go, or perhaps even something like node.js.

And by the way, I couldn't reproduce your original issue. When using `declare -i`, it *does* seem to evaluate your expression arithmetically and it does not seem to end up with any leading spaces.

```
declare -i qn_jobs
qn_jobs=$(jobs | wc -l)
echo "x$qn_jobs"
# => x0
```

Comment: Well, I am beginner, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Sure, np. While I like bash for its nice interactive features and its incorporation of the csh ! history mechanism, it's way too complex to easily digest the manpage and learn shell programming. On Linux you may want to install dash, if for no other reason than to get a readable manpage.  Here is another easy one with mostly-pure-Posix features: http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sh++NetBSD-current (That's the shell dash is based on.)

Comment: Seriously? I had only heard little about "dash".. do you recommend it over Bash, even?

Comment: Yeah, if I do _not_ put the `-i` in there.. I get the spaces! Try it and let me know if you see that too..

Comment: So, even if I got criticism in the comments for using `-i` it does actually serve that microscopic purpose, doesn't it? (I liked your use of "microscopic", as you can see) ;)

Comment: Don't take it personally. Stackoverflow is one of the top 100 sites *in the world* and is instantly indexed by Google. Many people will visit some answers for years to come and so it's sometimes worth it to cover every base.

Comment: Oh, no. I don't take anything personally.. I am here to learn. That's all.